# How to check if git commit is doing work?

Tags: git, filesystems, commit, large-files

I called git commit on a massive directory with a huge number of images. I have been waiting for it to finish for easily 20 minutes now. I know git scales poorly with size so I am not sure if this is just git taking its time or if the process has been halted for some reason.

I would like to see git doing ANYTHING, printing something to the terminal, blinking a cursor... I just need to check that it's actually running and not sleeping or waiting for something, deadlocked, glitched...

Is this possible? I am on Ubuntu.

Comment: `git commit` is normally almost instantaneous, because most of the work is already done during `git add`. If you use `git commit -a`, that essentially runs `git add` on everything, which is the slow part.

Comment: I just did git commit, not git commit -a

Comment: I cannot overstate just how large this folder is there's easily millions of files (just trying to commit a subset of 5000 inside a subfolder)

Comment: `git commit` has to write out one `tree` object per (sub)directory, so if the tree is very bushy, that would be a lot of tree objects. Each tree object should be pretty quick. Then it has to write out the commit, which is one object, and update one branch name. Let's say there are 1000 trees total: Git will have to write 1002 files, to complete this commit. It could be a very slow `git status`, if your file system has slow `stat` operations, though, in which case setting some of the "skip stat operations" flags might help. I have not actually tried this in practice though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn on the Debug flags to see what is going on.

```
GIT_TRACE=1 <command>

# For example
GIT_TRACE=1 git commit
```

[image]